# Validating an e-mail address with unobtrusive javascript / MVC3 and DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive-validation

jQuery Validation makes it simple to validate an email address:

```
$("someForm").validate({
    rules: {
        SomeField: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                type: "POST",
                url: "CheckEmail"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This makes it so that SomeField is required, must be formatted as an e-mail address and also performs a remote call to the CheckEmail action (check for duplicates).

I like to make things as simple as possible so I can do a lot of the same stuff with Data Annotations:

```
public class RegisterModel {
    [Required]
    [Remote("CheckEmail", "Home", HttpMethod="POST")]
    public string SomeField { get; set; }
}
```

Does ASP.net MVC 3 / Data Annotations have a built-in/simple way to validate to make sure the e-mail address is in the correct format?

I would like it to produce unobtrusive javascript if possible.

Comment: Check this Example: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Email-model-validation-with-DataAnnotations-and-DataType-In-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does ASP.net MVC 3 / Data Annotations
>   have a built-in/simple way to validate
>   to make sure the e-mail address is in
>   the correct format?

Not built-in but you could use a `[RegularExpression]`. Scott Gu illustrated an example of such regex in a [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx). He wrote a custom `EmailAttribute` deriving from `RegularExpressionAttribute` to avoid repeating logic.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to write my own attribute such as [Email]. How could I do that and have it produce unobtrusive javascript. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Dismissile, checkout the Scott Gu blog post. In it he derives from `RegularExpressionAttribute` and because of this client validation will work automatically because the Regex attribute already registers a jquery adapter.

Comment: Cool thanks. I skimmed it but I didn't see that he actually derived it.

Answer (score 11):

I think this is the code you are looking for (this is similar to ScottGu's example but also shows the DisplayName in the default error message instead of the property name):

```
public class EmailAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    private const string defaultErrorMessage = "'{0}' must be a valid email address";

    public EmailAttribute() : 
        base("^[a-z0-9_\\+-]+(\\.[a-z0-9_\\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\\.[a-z0-9]+)*\\.([a-z]{2,4})$")
    { }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(defaultErrorMessage, name);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
                                            ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (!base.IsValid(value))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(
                    FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Then your model property would look like this:

```
    [DisplayName("My Email Address")]
    [Email]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 9):

The [Data Annotation Extensions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/Email/Create) library has an `[Email]` attribute that allows for validating an email address.

There is also a [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2011/02/23/introducing-data-annotations-extensions.aspx) outlining how to use the library.

Comment: What Vadim meant to say was that there's a NuGet package now available that includes built-in DataAnnotations for Email, Date, CreditCard and others.  Very nice.  Project website:  http://dataannotationsextensions.org.

Answer (score 0):

EmailAddress attribute is built into framework already, no need for Data Annotation Extensions or other logic: [Email model validation with DataAnnotations and DataType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989081/email-model-validation-with-dataannotations-and-datatype)