# Email model validation with DataAnnotations and DataType

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, email, model

I have following model:

```
public class FormularModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Position { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Webcode { get; set; }
}
```

Required validation works fine. But when i try with DataType it doesn't react.

Here is my razor code for the email control:

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor
          (model => model.Email, 
           new { @style = "width: 175px;", @class = "txtField" }
          ) *
```

So, anyone know an answer?

TIA

Comment: Check this Example: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Email-model-validation-with-DataAnnotations-and-DataType-In-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 150, accepted):

`DataType` attribute is used for formatting purposes, not for validation.

I suggest you use [ASP.NET MVC 3 Futures](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781) for email validation.

Sample code:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[EmailAddress]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

---

If you happen to be using `.NET Framework 4.5`, there's now a built in `EmailAddressAttribute` that lives in [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute.aspx).

Comment: but it accepts 'something@domain' . i guess i will go with regular expression this time.

Comment: As we cant give custom error message. Am using this following way instead.  [EmailValidation(ErrorMessage = "The Email Address already exists")]
      [RegularExpression( "^[a-z0-9_\\+-]+(\\.[a-z0-9_\\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9]+)*\\.([a-z]{2,4})$" , ErrorMessage = "Invalid email format." )]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your e-mail address."), StringLength(50)]
      public string Email { get; set; }

Comment: That Regex will fail for "ryan.o'neal@gmail.com"

Answer (score 3):

I have looked at the source code (reverse engineered by Reflector) and `DataType` variants are actually not even implemented! (This was for `DateType.Date`)

So it is not going to work.

I would personally use `RegexValidation` for email.

---

For clarity, here is the implementation of `IsValid` in class `DataTypeAttribute`:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: hehehe... everything is valid! =)

Comment: Regex validation of email addresses is a really bad idea; the RFC allows to many weird permutations to make a regex feasible. Even tagged emails, as supported by GMail, usually get rejected as invalid, despite being perfectly valid.  (http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/ points this out well). http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/78353/how-far-should-one-take-e-mail-address-validation explores the various options, but the only 100% guarantee is to email the address and check for bounces.

Answer (score 2):

I used this regex pattern which will allow some of the newer longer extensions (.mynewsite, etc).

```
@"^[\w-_]+(\.[\w!#$%'*+\/=?\^`{|}]+)*@((([\-\w]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,20})|(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))$"
```

**Not Valid**, among others too:

- email@com
- email-o'neil@mysite.com  <-- doesn't like the tick, oh well.

**Examples that work:**

- email@m.superlongextension

Comment: For those implementing Regex format validations. This can impact the performance of your application.

Answer (score -7):

I think you need to add at html code one componente `Html.ValidationMessageFor`. This component shows the validation.

The code may be (using razor):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
```

try it.