# call MVC Validator in a get method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation, data-annotations

In my Controllor, in the get methode, I create My viewModel with elment from querystrings.
I need to validate email in MyViewModel, how can call my validator [EmailValidator]??

```
 public ActionResult Index(string countryCode)
    {
        var loginViewModel = _loginViewModelFactory.GetLoginViewModel();
        if (**ifvalid(loginViewModel.Mail**))
        {
            _loginViewModelFactory.mail=string.empty;
        }
        return View(loginViewModel);
    }
```

this is my model:

```
  public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [MailValidator]
        public string Mail { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you want to add validations to the email feild?

Comment: I have a validator but I need to call it in the get method: when the email field is not valid i change the value of the field to string.empty

Comment: use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989081/email-model-validation-with-dataannotations-and-datatype).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public ActionResult Index(string countryCode)
{
    var loginViewModel = _loginViewModelFactory.GetLoginViewModel();
    ModelState.Clear();
    TryValidateModel(loginViewModel)
    if (ModelState["Mail"].Errors.Any())
    {
        _loginViewModelFactory.mail=string.empty;
    }
    return View(loginViewModel);
}
```