# Validation doesn't work on Blazor Server Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I defined a form `LogInForm.cs` like this :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PollingInstitute.Data.LogIn
{
    public class LogInForm
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "This field require a mail adress (example : abc@xyz.com)")]
        public string Mail { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And a login screen `LogIn.razor` like this :

```
@page "/login"
@using PollingInstitute.Data.LogIn
@inject LogInService _LogInService

<h3>Login</h3>

<EditForm Model="@logInForm" OnValidSubmit="@TryLogIn">

    <div>
        <label>Mail Adress : </label><InputText @bind-Value="@logInForm.Mail"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>logInForm.Mail)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Password : </label><InputText @bind-Value="@logInForm.Password"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(()=>logInForm.Password)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>

    <div>

        @if (!IsDisabled)
        {
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        }
        else
        {
            <label>Please wait...</label>
        }
    </div>
    <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>
</EditForm>

@code {

    LogInForm logInForm = new LogInForm();
    protected bool IsDisabled { get; set; } = false;

    async void TryLogIn()
    {
        if (IsDisabled == true)
        {
            IsDisabled = true;
            StateHasChanged();
            bool result = (await _LogInService.TryLogIn(logInForm));
            Console.WriteLine("Logging status : " + (result ? "Sucess" : "Failure"));
            IsDisabled = false;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

When I'm filling (or not) the fields, it's always indicating them as valid, even though it's supposed to be not valid.

I checked the `_Imports.razor` and it got the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms` library.
I tried with Chrome and Firefox and it's always giving the same result.
I checked if javascript was on, and it was.

So what I'm doing wrong ? Is there anything to do with my code ? Do I have to add something in the `Startup.cs` file ? I made a Blazor app as a tutorial using the validation system and it was working flawlessly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem here is simply that you've forgotten to add the component which actually performs the validation.  To fix that, add this line below your `<EditForm Model="@logInForm" OnValidSubmit="@TryLogIn">` line:

```html
      <DataAnnotationsValidator />
```

Also, the `[DataType]` attribute is for formatting rather than validation. The validation annotation for an email address is `[EmailAddress]`, so add that too and it should work as expected. More on that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8989157/1879019).

As a slight aside on this; I came from the WinForms world where validation often felt like an unknowable black box.  In Blazor it's really well documented [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and also [in the code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/909f1d368f1e195e9fa2368e12d07b5b5584f8e8/src/Components/Forms/src/EditContext.cs), so if you want to learn more about it at any point it's actually possible.  [This blog by Steve Sanderson](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/04/blazor-fluentvalidation/) has some really good outline info in the "Blazor’s forms and validation extensibility" section.

Comment: It works now, thanks. Oddly, the `[DataType(DataType.EmailAdress)]` attribute doesn't work but surely i'm misunderstanding its function.

Comment: @PepperTiger `DataType` is for formatting rather than validation.  The validation annotation is `[EmailAddress]` so add that too and it should work as expected.  More on that here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8989157/1879019

Comment: @PepperTiger I can't find a list of just the validation attributes, but if you look for the ones that include "validate" in their descriptions in this list you should get a pretty good idea:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations?view=netframework-4.8